# Websocket server implementation with x/net library trowing 403

Tags: go, websocket

I am trying to implement a websocket server **using `x/net/websocket` standard library.**

My attempt so far looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
)

type Server struct {
    baseUri     string
    connections map[string][]*websocket.Conn
}

func initServer(baseUri string) *Server {
    return &Server{
        baseUri: baseUri,
    }
}

func (server *Server) handleConnections() {
    http.Handle("/ws", websocket.Handler(server.listenConnections))
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func (server *Server) listenConnections(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("New connection established")
    for {
        fmt.Println("FOO")
    }
}

func main() {
    server := initServer("/ws")
    server.handleConnections()
}
```

Attempting to connect to `ws://localhost:3000/ws` using multiple ws clients, I always get the same error: a `403-Forbidden`.
I even tried the [official doc's example](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket#example-Handler) and am still getting the it. Am I missing something obvious? Like a default port blocking or similar?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: You may want to use a different port to reproduce the issue. Using `3000` as in my example, if not available, just breaks the program's execution.

Edit 2: You can use a client like [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat) and do `websocat 'ws://localhost:3000/ws'` to attempt to connect to the server

Comment: The 2nd line of the package document said:
"This package currently lacks some features found in an alternative and more actively maintained WebSocket package: https://pkg.go.dev/nhooyr.io/websocket". Maybe you should not use the package.

Comment: The [websocket.Handler documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket#Handler) says *if you want to accept non-browser clients, which do not send an Origin header, set a Server.Handshake that does not check the origin.*  Either set the origin using a websocat command line flag or implement a server handshake function.  Better yet, switch to the Gorilla or Nhooyr packages to avoid this and other problems.  The x/net/websocket package is **not** in the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up, but with nice insights:
If like myself you were following Anthony GG's [walkthrough on creating a websocket server on Go from scratch](https://youtu.be/JuUAEYLkGbM?si=pwTCuJzr6I4rtm-Q), please don't. Video is outdated and although it gives a great intuition on how to create one, is better to (and no shame on) learn using gorilla's websocket library.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

type Server struct {
    baseUri     string
    connections map[string][]*websocket.Conn
    router      *mux.Router
    setup       *http.Server
}

func initServer(baseUri string) *Server {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    return &Server{
        baseUri: baseUri,
        router:  router,
        setup: &http.Server{
            Handler:      router,
            Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8000",
            WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
            ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
        },
    }
}

func (server *Server) handleConnections() {
    server.router.HandleFunc("/ws/{var}", server.listenConnections)
    server.setup.ListenAndServe()
}

func (server *Server) listenConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    connection, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        _, message, err := connection.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }

        connection.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
        go messageHandler(message)
    }
    fmt.Println("Out of loop")
}

func messageHandler(message []byte) {
    fmt.Println(string(message))
}

func main() {
    server := initServer("/ws")
    server.handleConnections()
}
```

I'm also using `gorilla/mux` to be able to use path parameters (not sure why http handler could not).
Notice how I changed `http.Handle` to `mux.Router.HandleFunc`.
As user @Cerise pointed in the comments, `x/net/websocket` package is not in the standard library, but the original issue was not resolved just adding the `Origin` header either.

Hopefully this skips a few headaches of other people learning Go like myself.